# read the third node of xml based on second node in java

Tags: java, xml

how can i read the third node of the xml which is the product based on the second node product group using java.  i want to get the products based on the product code

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <Restaurant>
                <ProductGroup id="1">
                    <label>BURGERS</label>
                    <image_url>burger.png</image_url>
                    <Product>
                        <label>Hamburger</label>
                        <productCode>aab</productCode>
                        <img_url>Hamburger.png</img_url>
                        <price>129.46</price>
                    </Product>
                    <Product>
                        <label>Cheeseburger</label>
                        <productCode>cch</productCode>
                        <img_url>Cheeseburger.png</img_url>
                        <price>129.46</price>
                    </Product>      
                </ProductGroup>
                <ProductGroup id="2">
                    <label>FRIES/ONION RING</label>
                    <image_url>friesonionring.png</image_url>
                    <Product>
                        <label>Fries</label>
                        <productCode>FRS</productCode>
                        <img_url>fries.png</img_url>
                        <price>50.46</price>
                    </Product>
                    <Product>
                        <label>Onion Rings</label>
                        <productCode>ONR</productCode>
                        <img_url>onionring.png</img_url>
                        <price>50.46</price>
                    </Product>      
                </ProductGroup>
            </Restaurant>
```

Comment: So you want to fetch the product codes in a specific category, right? You can use an XPath query like this "/Restaurant/ProductGroup[@id='2']/Product/productCode" ... or to get the product with a specific ID from a specific group: "/Restaurant/ProductGroup[@id='2']/Product[productCode='aab']" ... or this one to get a specific product from anywhere in the document "//Product[productCode='cch']" ... Check out the XPath API: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html

Comment: You need to use xml parser for java.
[This](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a query language designed specifically for this kind of tasks. It's called XPath. You can use it to select specific nodes from your XML tree by specifying a path similar to the ones you know from your operating system or web addresses. It also gives you the ability to specify a variety of conditions, which determine the nodes you select.

Let's take a look at a couple of examples.

You can use an XPath query like this to select all product codes from a group specified by the value of its `id` attribute:

```
/Restaurant/ProductGroup[@id='2']/Product/productCode
```

To get the product with a specific ID from a specific group, you'd want to add another condition. The following query also requires the `Product` element to have a child element called `productCode` with the value of '`aab'` :

```
/Restaurant/ProductGroup[@id='2']/Product[productCode='aab']
```

It's also possible not to specify the entire structure of your document and only require a `Product` element to be somewhere in the document and not necessarily in a ProductGroup that is a child of Restaurant.

```
//Product[productCode='cch']
```

There are many tutorials on XPath tha will help you to get an understanding of this simple language. It's powerful, very easy to understand, widely implemented and does not require your code to be verbose.

To use its power in a Java app, check out the XPath API: http://ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html